# Adobe AIR NativeWindow Inner Width & height

Tags: actionscript, air, nativewindow

When calling `nativeWindow.width` in Adobe AIR, it returns the width of the window include the border. How can I get the inner width / height of the window?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The innerWidth and innerHeight properties equal the stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight properties minus the thickness of any automatic scrollbars displayed by the window.**

Check this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#bounds) for more details